# Drupal 8 Try catch not working

Tags: 8

When I am trying to catch an error i Drupal 8 I am unable to catch the error, I get a message: `The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.` and the error get logged in the error log report:

```
   try {
      $decoded = JWT::decode($tokenOutput->access_token, $array_publicKeysWithKIDasArrayKey, array('RS256'));
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
      die($e->getMessage());
    }
```

I tried the same code in a stand alone php app and everything is working properly.

It not the error itself that is causing me trouble but the fact that I cannot catch it and that my Drupal script die to a message such as `The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.`

The error is the following : `Firebase\JWT\BeforeValidException: Cannot handle token prior to 2017-04-04T15:51:13-0400 in Firebase\JWT\JWT::decode() (line 115 of /vagrant/drupal/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/JWT.php).`. I want to be able to catch the error and manage it in order not to have the script break.

Comment: Are you including the JWT class with `use Path\To\Namespace\JWT`? Was it included via Composer?

Comment: Perhaps you should use a logger instead of exit/die? You should provide the PHP error message in your question. Unfortunately I do not think you can edit your question yet...

Comment: It could even be an issue with the argument list. We need to see the PHP error and have more details.

Comment: You've done something that can't be caught with `try...catch` (e.g. syntax error pre-php7) which is why the custom error handler gets involved. Your watchdog should have details of the error but without seeing it it's impossible to advise

Comment: Clive, actually your answer was right, I had the wrong try...catch syntax.